# Best way to secure a Winform page ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, security

In a Web application we define roles, forms authentication etc. for security, but what should be the best way to secure a Winform ?

Actually I am making desktop application in which I hide login page after successful login and show `DisplayForm` like this ;

```
//On successful login
this.Hide()
Form newForm = new DisplayForm();
newForm.Show();
```

But I don't know if it's the right way or not? I want the user to be able to see this `DisplayForm` only after successful login.

Any guidance please ?

Comment: You just don't.  You are not talking to a complete stranger on the Internet, you have a known user that already provided his credentials to login to Windows.  Which gave him his assigned rights, including and not limited to the right to mess with your program and defeat some kind of login scheme you'd want to impose on top of the existing one.

Comment: You can use Delegate once You Logged in Succesfully... Fire the Delegae from the New Form

Comment: Security is not just hiding or showing a form. You have to think about what you want secure. For example the data or a function or algorithm. Is the client running within a regulatied environment or not?

Comment: @HansPassant  that's what my second concern is ! how to assign rights , one way is using web services, because the data showing in the app is coming from remote desktop .. but the issue in this is that winForms do not support cookie etc therefore for every transaction i have to check user's credentials but that would not be efficient ,any other way ?

Comment: @peer i want to know that how can i secure a page which will open only after filling correct credentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow on from Mike's answer this is the implementation I used (as requested by the OP):

Add the following to the function definition:

```
[PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "<Your role>")]
public void YourFunction()
{
    .. do something
}
```

Where `<Your Role>` is the AD role you want to restrict access to.

Then wrap your function call like this:

```
        try
        {
            YourFunction();
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You do not have permission to perform this action.", "Access Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks @bhs , just two things i want to confirm.. do i need to add anything to app.config and how can i define roles at runtime because my database values are coming from the remote site.

Comment: I didn't do anything in app.config and the roles come from active directory.

Answer (score 2):

Let me preface my answer with the following general remark: *There is no absolute security in WinForms applications.* Nothing stops the user from decompiling your application, removing any login requirements you might have added and recompiling it.

That said, I think your approach is correct. `DisplayForm` won't show until you, the programmer, explicitly tell it to do so. Thus, if you only call `someInstanceOfDisplayForm.Show()` after authentication has happened, that is fine.

As an additional security measure (to safeguard against some programming mistakes), a common practice is to

- set some global variable¹ `UserLoggedIn`, after the user has successfully logged in and
- check this value in `Form_Open` of `DisplayForm` (or any other form you want to protect).

---

<sub>¹ ... or Singleton property or some other kind of global storage. Yes, global variables are evil, but I think it is justified in this case, since a user logged into an application is a prime example of a legitimate "global state". If required, I'll gladly discuss this further in the comments.</sub>

Comment: "There is no absolute security in WinForms applications". This is true for a single machine app, but you can secure the data that the application uses. For example, using file system ACLs, authorised web services or DB access controls. This is much easier if you use windows auth instead of rolling your own, of course.

Comment: @heinzi , but there is one minor issue .. when i hide something ,it will be hidden and if user close the other displayed form .. the hidden form will nt close ! what should be the other way ?

Comment: @hridya: I'm not sure I understand your question. Maybe you should start a new SO question for that?

Comment: @Heinzi yes but now i am checking user credentials on button click and add controls pro-grammatically to the same form.. it is little time consuming but i feel this is the best way.. Thanks for the support !

Answer (score 2):

The best way in my opinion is to use Windows Authentication (as suggested in the comment from Hans Passant) and do not implement your own login dialog and user store.

In this way, you can always make authorisation decisions by examining the current user principal (e.g. `Thread.CurrentPrinciple`). The granting or denying of application permissions can then be done on the basis of their Active Direcory memberships, which are all accessible by looking at the user principle.

The advantages of this are:

- It prevents people bypassing your security by going directly to your assemblies
- It allows your admins to control application permissions using familiar Active Directory group membership - no need for you to write code for this and reduced chance of people forgetting to remove application permissions when users change role

Comment: I've done this recently using `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` - there is a link to a good starting point [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx)

Comment: @bhs, i have seen the link looking something new and good.. can u please explain how u implemented this ,with some small example..

Comment: @hridya I've added a new answer as it's easier to format the code there