# How to remove TextBox with password from the memory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, passwords

I have simple Login form.

After the user have digit password I need to destroy textbox to the memory.

Is it enough to do this?

```
txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
txtPassword = null;
System.GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Pragmatically calling of `GC` is not a very good thing.

Comment: No.  The text can still be in the `TextBox`; some other variable or object that you may have a reference to.  You might want to consider WPF's `PasswordBox` and `SecureString`

Comment: Simply `txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;` doesn't work ?

Comment: @MickyD I trasfer the text in SecureString

Comment: @Amit no.  That won't do anything for  any potential orphaned `string` object with clear text password

Comment: @MickyD I didn't consider any `string` object which has been derived from `txtPassword.Text` , suppose there may not any such exclusive string, doing `txtPassword.Text = string.Empty` will not be enough for overwirting original value of it from its reference (memory)

Comment: @Amit there is no gurantee that the memory will be cleaned if you call the `GC`

Comment: And what are you doing with that password after that?

Comment: @Amit you can assign `.Text` anything you want.  The password can still be floating in memory somewhere unprotected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to free memory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066200/what-is-the-correct-way-to-free-memory-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Not sure why you voted to close your **own** question as a duplicate.  The linked post isn't particularly relevant

Comment: Off-topic perhaps - Possible duplicate of [Best way to secure a Winform page ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739263/best-way-to-secure-a-winform-page).   The suggestions are is that you don't use a password at all and use Windows authentication.  Check out _Hans Passant's_ comment on that page

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be interested in [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> An instance of the System.String class is both immutable and, when no longer needed, cannot be programmatically scheduled for garbage collection; that is, the instance is read-only after it is created, and it is not possible to predict when the instance will be deleted from computer memory. Because System.String instances are immutable, operations that appear to modify an existing instance actually create a copy of it to manipulate. Consequently, if a String object contains sensitive information such as a password, credit card number, or personal data, there is a risk the information could be revealed after it is used because your application cannot delete the data from computer memory.
>
> A SecureString object is similar to a String object in that it has a text value. However, the value of a SecureString object is pinned in memory, may use a protection mechanism, such as encryption, provided by the underlying operating system, can be modified until your application marks it as read-only, and can be deleted from computer memory either by your application calling the Dispose method or by the .NET Framework garbage collector.

Comment: I transfer the data String and after  in SecureString but I need to destroy the TextBox with password and the transition String Variable to the memory.

Comment: Insufficient.  WinForms (the subject of the OP's question) does not support `SecureString` for the `Text` property or similar, unlike WPF's `PasswordBox`.  `PasswordBox` doesn't even have a `string Text` property instead it is a `SecureString SecurePassword`.  This sets up the foundation for secure strings suitable for passwords.  Attempting to use `SecureString` as an afterthought for WinForms is risky

Comment: @daniele3004 - transfering data from a `string` into a `SecureString` is useless (because the `string` is still in memory and you won't get rid of it that easily; which is what your question basically is). The security of `SecureString` is only achieved by *never having the "complete" `string` in (insecure) memory*. You add it character by character, keypress by keypress. Like in the example in the linked MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

Set it into:

```
txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\0';
```

Comment: Please add a (short) explanation. I understand you intend to rewrite the string so it does not contain the text anymore, so it does not include the password anymore. Could you develop your answer?